# Android: Throwing error while creating table

Tags: java, android

I have created 2 tables in a db. 1 is working fine. TABLE_NAME2 is giving error while creating.

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
         public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "abc.db";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "table1";
    public static final String COL2 = "col1";
    public static final String COL3 = "Date";
    public static final String COL4 = "Cost";
    public static final String COL5 = "loc1";
    public static final String COL6 = "loc2";
    public static final String COL7 = "Description";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "signup";
    public static final String USER_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String USER_MOBILE = "MOBILE";
    public static final String USER_PASS = "PASSWORD";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);


    }@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + "("
            + USER_NAME + "TEXT,"
            + USER_EMAIL + "TEXT,"
            + USER_MOBILE + "TEXT, "
            + USER_PASS + "TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE Table " + TABLE_NAME1 + "("// + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COL2 + " TEXT,"
            + COL3 + " TEXT,"
            + COL4 + " TEXT,"
            + COL5 + " TEXT,"
            + COL6 + " TEXT,"
            + COL7 + " TEXT)");
     }



    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME1);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);


}

public boolean insertHomeDataDB(String locName, String date, String cost, String startLoc, String endLoc, String description){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, locName);
    contentValues.put(COL3, date);
    contentValues.put(COL4, cost);
    contentValues.put(COL5, startLoc);
    contentValues.put(COL6, endLoc);
    contentValues.put(COL7, description);
    //contentValues.put(COL8, userId);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, contentValues);
    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

public boolean insertSignupDataDB(String name, String email, String mobile, String pass){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(USER_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(USER_EMAIL, email);
    contentValues.put(USER_MOBILE, mobile);
    contentValues.put(USER_PASS, pass);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllHomeData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Cursor res;
    String[] projection = {COL2,COL3,COL4};
    res = db.query(TABLE_NAME1,projection,null,null,null,null,null);
    return res;

}

public Cursor getAllProfileData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Cursor res;
    String[] projection={USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL,USER_MOBILE,USER_PASS};
    res = db.query(TABLE_NAME2, projection,null,null,null,null,null);
    return res;
}
}
```

From this page I am sending data to DatabaseHelper Class to insert data. It shows the toast "successful signup", but is showing error in Logs, and also it is not navigating to LoginActivity class. it is navigating to MainActivity. Even else part is not working. when i put different passwords it gives error app stopped.

```
if(etSignPass.getText().toString().equals(etSignConPass.getText().toString())){

                boolean queryResult = dbHelper.insertSignupDataDB(etSignName.getText().toString(),
                        etSignEmail.getText().toString(), etSignMobile.getText().toString(), etSignPass.getText().toString());
                if(queryResult=true){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Successfully Signed up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        navigateUpTo(new Intent(SignUp.this,LoginActivity.class));
                    }

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            else{
                etSignConPass.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                onClicSignUp();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the full logcat. (unless the answer provided already fixed it). Nice spot @hexafraction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + "("
>         + USER_NAME + "TEXT,"
>         + USER_EMAIL + "TEXT,"
>         + USER_MOBILE + "TEXT, "
>         + USER_PASS + "TEXT)");
> db.execSQL("CREATE Table " + TABLE_NAME1 + "("// + COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
>         + COL2 + " TEXT,"
>         + COL3 + " TEXT,"
>         + COL4 + " TEXT,"
>         + COL5 + " TEXT,"
>         + COL6 + " TEXT,"
>         + COL7 + " TEXT)");
> ```

There is a very big and important difference between the SQL you are running to create table 2 and table 1. In creating table 1, the SQL is of the format `CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 TEXT, ...`

However, when you create table 2, you are missing the space between the column name and `TEXT`. Add a space to your `"TEXT"` string literals, or better, use a prepared statement if available.